React Button Div Animation Issue: Opening and Closing Behavior Problem
I am new to react
if I close all the divs of the first button and then click second button at that time, second button divs are not opening.
Similarly if I close all the divs of the second button and then click first button div is not opening.
Can you let me know how to fix it .
even animation not working fine, all three div should open from right to left when I click on the button
Providing code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-by5upk?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FApp.css&terminal=dev
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(null);
  const [divStates, setDivStates] = useState({
    first: [false, false, false],
    second: [false, false, false],
    fourth: [false, false, false],
    // ... Add more sets for other buttons like 'third', 'fourth'
  });

  const handleClick = (tabName) => {
    if (currentTab === tabName) {
      setCurrentTab(null);
      closeAllDivs();
    } else {
      setCurrentTab(tabName);
      setDivStates((prevStates) => ({
        ...prevStates,
        [tabName]: prevStates[tabName].fill(true),
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleCloseDiv = (tabName, index) => {
    setDivStates((prevStates) => ({
      ...prevStates,
      [tabName]: prevStates[tabName].map((isOpen, i) =>
        i === index ? false : isOpen
      ),
    }));

    if (divStates[tabName].every((isOpen) => !isOpen)) {
      closeAllDivs();
    }
  };

  const closeAllDivs = () => {
    setCurrentTab(null);
    setDivStates(
      Object.keys(divStates).reduce(
        (acc, tab) => ({
          ...acc,
          [tab]: divStates[tab].fill(false),
        }),
        {}
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="slide-divs-container">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick('first')}>
          {currentTab === 'first' ? 'Close All 1' : 'first'}
        </button>
        {currentTab === 'first' && (
          <div className="slide-divs">
            {divStates.first.map((isOpen, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className={`slide-div ${isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}`}
                style={{ animationDelay: `${index * 100}ms` }}
              >
                <p>Div Content (First Group) {index + 1}</p>
                <button
                  className="close-btn"
                  onClick={() => handleCloseDiv('first', index)}
                >
                  X
                </button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* // ... other code ... */}
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick('second')}>
          {currentTab === 'second' ? 'Close All 2' : 'Second'}
        </button>
        {currentTab === 'second' && (
          <div className="slide-divs">
            {divStates.second.map((isOpen, index) => (
              <div
                key={`second-group-div-${index}`} // Add a unique key
                className={`slide-div ${isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}`}
                style={{ animationDelay: `${index * 100}ms` }}
              >
                <p>Div Content (Second Group) {index + 1}</p>
                <button
                  className="close-btn"
                  onClick={() => handleCloseDiv('second', index)}
                >
                  X
                </button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* // ... other code ... */}
      {/* ... Structures for other buttons  */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


You cannot click the second button because "slide-divs" div is positioned over it.

@palindrom thanks for your response, after you close all the divs and if I click the second button still corresponding divs of second button not opening. can you fix it in the sandbox...so confusing

I dont think you undertood the problem. Here I added only background: red; so that you can see slide-divs is covering the buttons thus you cannot click the buttons at all. You need to fix your css. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ksoz6d?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FApp.css&terminal=dev

@palindrom  can you let me know how to fix the css....I tried giving  <div style={{ marginLeft: '536px' }}> for second button but still its not working 100% ...is it possible to update the fiddle with proper css https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-5jfgmo?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FApp.css&terminal=dev you can zoom out and test it
